# Django attribute is not up to date

Tags: python, django

I'm using Django / Postgresql, and I want to build some kind of media player behavior : start playing when asked, play until further command, and stop playing when asked.

My Django model is designed as follows :

- a boolean attribute *state*
- a function that switches the *state* value, and if it's true, calls the looping function
- a function that loops while the *state* attribute is True, and stops when it is False.

The code is as follows:

```
state = models.BooleanField(default=False)

def switchState(self):
    print 'switching from %s to %s' % (self.state, not(self.state))
    self.state = not(self.state)
    self.save()
    if self.state :
        self.loop()

def loop(self):
    while self.state:
        print 'looping'
        time.sleep( 1 )
        print 'stopped looping'
```

Behavior :

- when I call switchState() on a model instance, *state* is set to True (I can see it in the database) and the loop() function starts printing lines
- when I call switchState() again, *state* is set to False (again, I can see it in the database) but then, the loop() function does not stop. When I print *state*, its value is still True...

I can't get an up to date value of that damned *state* attribute.
I must be missing something, but what ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Control audio playing in server via web?

Comment: Probably a transaction issue. Since `loop` executes continually, it's in its own transaction, which means it'll never see updates made outside that transaction.

Comment: @ Daniel Roseman : That sounds pretty relevant. But what should I do ?

Comment: @ ssapkota : the loop function is actually a batch process, which I would like to be able to stop / pause

Comment: See the [transaction docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/#transactions).

Comment: I read the doc you mentionned, as well as [this one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/transactions/) but that does not give me any anwer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I finally found an answer. As Daniel Roseman told me, the problem wad due to the loop function, which was looping in its own transaction, not being able to see what happened in another transaction.

I first tried to force a refresh on my instance, with the new refresh_from_db() function, but that didn't work at all (I still don't get why, please tell me if you know).

As Daniel suggested, I read again the Django transaction doc, and finally found out a solution that seems to work. The idea is to allow the loop function to update the instance at each loop, using the *with transaction.atomic()* command.

```
def loop(self): 
    vTest = Source.objects.get(id=self.id)
    while vTest:
        with transaction.atomic():
            vTest = Source.objects.get(id=self.id).state    
            print 'looping'
            time.sleep( 1 )
    print 'stopped looping'
```

Nb : you can't use

```
vTest = self.state
```

instead of

```
vTest = Source.objects.get(id=self.id).state
```

Maybe it's not the right way to do it, feel free to correct me if I'm wrong.